# Run executable with stdin set in console

Tags: bash, stdin

A have a linux executable named "foo". The program foo waits until the user writes a string (using scanf) from stdin, and then print the string (to stdout).

How can I set the run the  program, so it won't wait the user writes a string, i.e., it will immediately will read a sting from stdin and then outputs the string?

P.S The input is not given from a file, but from the console.

Note: a followup question for this problem is published in [Paramiko: Run executable with stdin set in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744482/paramiko-run-executable-with-stdin-set-in-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [here-string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) may suit your case:

```
./foo <<< "whatever_passed_to_foo"
```